# How to gracefully shut down all activities and close all running threads in an Android app?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, threadpool, terminate

At the moment, in each one of my activities I have this method:

```
private void registerReceiverClose(){
    Activity activity = this;
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("CLOSE_ALL");
    broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            activity.finish();
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
}
```

and this one as well:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

They're triggered by the following logout button:

```
    Button logout = findViewById(R.id.logout_button);
    logout.setOnClickListener(click -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent("CLOSE_ALL");
        this.sendBroadcast(intent);
    });
```

One thing that I'm sure is not closing in the right way, is that I have this code:

```
private static final ScheduledExecutorService pollingScheduledExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

private static final Object lock = new Object();
private static ScheduledFuture<?> currentRunningTask;

public void longPoll() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        if (currentRunningTask != null) {
            currentRunningTask.cancel(true);
        }
        try {
            currentRunningTask = pollingScheduledExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, 0, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
    }
}

public void request() {
    Thread requestThread = new Thread(this);
    requestThread.start();
}
```

which continues to issue requests even after I *think* I should be logged out, which causes errors on the server.

How can I make sure all the threads stop gracefully and the application closes down in the right way?

Answer (score 1):

You could wrapthe polling code inside of a [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services). This service can then be stopped using

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class); 
stopService(intent);
```

Inside of the service, you can override `onDestroy()` to clean resources up.